# SNS - Get endpoint arn using Token?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Is it not possible to get a device endpoint using the `Token`?

I'm able to create a `endpoint arn` using the device token:

```
//let androidDeviceId = c6RcYuiyRqiMMrm9JiFH3W:APA91bHq2bf1VBDHTYhivTmylN24NkYWd9qbS5FKPfLnHV5NSvmoiKG8f_Iz7OLJ9lDUN6kfpC-....;

const endPointParams = {
        PlatformApplicationArn: process.env.AWS_SNS_ARN,
        Token: androidDeviceId
    }

   
    try {
        const result = await sns.createPlatformEndpoint(endPointParams).promise();;
        console.log(result);

        return res.status(200).send({ success: true });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send({ reason: err });
    }
```

[image]

But I can't seem to find a way to get the `endpoint arn` using the `token`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html

There's `getEndpointAttributes` but that only gets the token using the `arn endpoint`:

[image]

How would I get the endpoint using the token?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to create another `dynamodb` table to track the device `token` as well as the `endpoint arn`.

So after creating a `endpoint arn` I would insert that into my `token-endpoint-table`

```
//Creates the endpoint arn using the token (the device id)
let createEndpointResult = await sns.createPlatformEndpoint(endPointParams).promise();

let endpointArn = createEndpointResult.EndpointArn;

//Inserts into the token-endpoint-table
await upsertDeviceId(androidDeviceId, endpointArn);
```

I'd then query that table with the `token` as the `primary key` to get the endpoint `arn.`

If someone has a better solution please share.